# In .Net with AWS how do I change IAM Roles?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services

I am building our first test application to use DynamoDB from a Widows Service application.

I've got as far as this:

```
    public async Task<int> GoFishAsync()
    {
        string accessKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        string secretKey = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.EUWest1);

        var tableResponse = await client.ListTablesAsync();

        return tableResponse.TableNames.Count;
    }
```

However, I use a Role with rights to actually access our databases.
How do I add this role?

I tried adding:

```
        AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest();
        roleRequest.RoleArn = "arn: aws:iam::1234567890:role / PowerUserParis";
        roleRequest.RoleSessionName = "ServerApp";
```

but I don't see hpw to add the RoleRequest to either the Client or Credentials?

I should add that in production we will be pulling in the actual credentials from our encrypted database.

Answer (score 0):

To assume a role you will need some credentials to call AssumeRole on the `Amazon.SecurityToken.AmazonSecurityTokenServiceClient` which comes from the AWSSDK.SecurityToken NuGet package. The response object from the AssumeRole will contain AWS credentials for the role that you can then use to construct other AWS service clients like the DynamoDB client.